# Upgrading AWS elasticsearch & logstash with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, terraform, aws-elasticsearch

I am currently trying to upgrade our AWS Elasticsearch (ES) with terraform and want to create two new clusters from the one that we currently have.

It would be preferable to do it through terraform as we have a huge cluster that is run through terraform so if we update through the console it would revert back when we apply the terraform. Has anyone any experience doing this from ES version 2.3 to version 5? I have been told to snapshot and restore but cant find any documentation on how to do this through terraform. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I think we have figured it out. You cannot upgrade from Elasticsearch version 2.3 through terraform as it is just to old. You need to manually create two new clusters, point you logs at that & then take a snapshot of the old cluster and restore it to the new one. After version 5 of elasticsearch I believe you can upgrade through the terraform as long as your provider (e.g. AWS) is at least version 1.55. This should not need a snapshot as the cluster will be updated in place, I have been informed